# Prevent dom0 IGP from being VGA-passed-through to HVM host with Xen4.4

Tags: nvidia, xen, display

Usually people want to VGA-passthrough their IGP, and there are a lot of documentation out there. However I *don't* want my IGP passed-through to the domU as it serves my dom0, only my secondary card (Multi-OS NVidia).

Currently everything is working fine with `gfx_passthrough=1`, except that when the domU takes control of the IGP it messes dom0's X server up (I cannot/don't know how to relaunch it, save for rebooting). It does not happen with `gfx_passthrough=0` (but then the secondary card does not work).

Would someone please be so kind as to point where I can find information regarding such matters? Need I somehow explicitly forbid the IGP device with VGA passthrough, contrary to PCI passthrough?

My running configuration:

- Dell PET620 server
- Xen4.4 with Ubuntu Server 14.04 as dom0 (stock kernels and all)
- domU (HVM) : Win7 / Mint17
- IGP : Matrox something, 16M RAM
- PCI card : NVidia Quadro K4000